# Shopify liquid : cart-template variant is not defined

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am simply allowing to checkout out of stock product to buy. When a customer wants to buy product has inventory less than zero and clicks on view cart from ajax cart, I simply want to show message " dispatch by 7 June." in `cart-template.liquid`.I have applied logic as given below. If required full code ready to share.

```
{% if variant.inventory_quantity < 1%}
<p id="dispatch" style="color: #f48c21">Will be dispatched by June 7</p>
{{variant.inventory_quantity}}
{% endif %}
<script>console.log(variant.inventory_quantity)</script>
```

when I print the message in `cart-template.liquid` without `if` condition I can see this message. I found that it does not print anything inside `{{}}` also checked with `console.log` gives error as `variant is not defined` My query Is do I need to define `variant` manually? if yes how? or need to use a different liquid variable to check inventory quantity of product less than zero? 
Let me know if any more are required. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have started printing all variant variable. I just simply added `item` before `variant.inventory_quantity` and it saves my day.

```
{% if item.variant.inventory_quantity < 1 %}
<p id="dispatch" style="color: #f48c21">Will be dispatched by June 7</p>
{% endif %}
```