# Shopify liquid :How to get variant inventory from ajax cart

Tags: shopify, liquid

This question sounds similar to my own question [cart-template-variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50549571/shopify-liquid-cart-template-variant-is-not-defined). I am doing the same thing with ajax cart `header.liquid`. I just wanted to access inventory from cart object same as `cart-template` question  `{% if item.variant.inventory_quantity < 1 %}`. I am initially trying to print `{{item.variant.inventory_quantity}}` into `header.liquid` since it is ajax cart. inside `{% for item in cart.items %}` I have printed `{{item.variant.inventory_quantity}}` but when I add in stock or out of stock product into the cart. It always returns 0. Which is the cart object property I am not passing properly?

I am actually following below advise but I have missed something here.

The code for Ajax cart is in header.liquid. It has a Cart object, which has many properties. See https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/cart#cart-items

One of them is items (i.e. cart.items), which gives all the items added to cart. Around line 100, you will see a for loop {% for item in cart.items %}.

Here item = line_item. The line_item has many properties. See https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/line_item.

One of them is variant. i.e. line_item.variant. So here inside for loop will be item.variant.

So now you have variant properties.  See https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/variant

variant.inventory_quantity is one of them.

header.liquid (Ready to share entire file if required.)

```
<form action="/checkout" method="post" id="cart">
    <ul data-money-format="{{ shop.money_format }}" data-shop-currency="{{ shop.currency }}" data-shop-name="{{ shop.name | escape }}">
      <li class="mm-subtitle"><a class="continue ss-icon" href="#cart"><span class="icon-close"></span></a></li>

      {% if cart.item_count == 0 %}
        <li class="empty_cart">{{ 'layout.general.empty_cart' | t }}</li>
      {% else %}
        {% for item in cart.items %}
            {{item.variant.inventory_quantity}}
        <a href="/#" >Will be dispatched by June 7</a>
          <li class="cart_item {% if forloop.last %}last_cart_item{% endif %}">
            <p class="mm-counter">
              <span class="icon-minus minus"></span><input type="number" min="0" class="quantity" name="updates[]" id="updates_{{ item.id }}" value="{{ item.quantity }}" data-line-id="{{ forloop.index }}" readonly /><span class="icon-plus plus"></span>
            </p>
            <a href="{{ item.url }}">
              {% if item.image %}
                <div class="cart_image">
                  <img src="{{ item | img_url: '410x' }}" alt="{{ item.title | escape }}" />
                </div>
              {% endif %}
              <div class="item_info">
                {{ item.product.title }}
                {% unless item.product.has_only_default_variant or item.variant.title contains "Title" %}
                  {% for option in item.product.options %}
                    {% unless option contains "Title" %}
                      - {{ item.variant.options[forloop.index0] }} {% unless forloop.last %}/{% endunless %}
                    {% endunless %}
                  {% endfor %}
                {% endunless %}

                {% if item.properties %}
                  {% for p in item.properties %}
                    {% if p.last != blank %}
                      <div class="line-item">
                        {{ p.first }}: {{ p.last }}
                      </div>
                    {% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}        
                <div class="price">
                  <span class="money">{{ item.price | money }}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
        <li class="mm-label">
          <p class="mm-counter price">
            <span class="money">{{ cart.total_price | money }}</span>
          </p>
          <a href="/cart">
            <strong>{{ 'layout.general.subtotal' | t }}</strong>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="mm-subtitle clearfix">
          {% if settings.display_special_instructions %}
            <textarea id="cart-note" name="note" rows="2" placeholder="{{ 'layout.general.cart_note' | t }}" class="clearfix">{{ cart.note }}</textarea>
          {% endif %}

          {% if settings.display_tos_checkbox %}
            <aside class="tos tos_checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" class="tos_agree" id="sliding_agree" required />
              <label class="tos_label" for="sliding_agree">
                {{ settings.tos_richtext }}
              </label>
            </aside>
          {% endif %}

          <input type="submit" class="action_button right" value="{{ 'layout.general.checkout' | t }}" />
          <a href="/cart" class="action_button edit_cart right">{{ 'layout.general.edit_cart' | t }}</a>
        </li>      
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </form>
```

Comment: `{{item.variant.inventory_quantity}}` _should_ be correct. What is the inventory_quantity that you're expecting for these products?

Comment: Confirmed that your code should work - I copy-pasted it into my dev store's theme and got correct numbers.   Can you also confirm that in your admin, "Shopify tracks this product's inventory" is turned on? When it's turned off, I think Shopify defaults  to either 0 or 1, so you may be getting default values instead of real values